# what does analyzing an algorithm in the stochastic setting mean?

Tags: machine-learning, stochastic-approximation

Does stochastic setting for a data mean that the distribution of the data is fixed, and data points are getting generated i.i.d from that distribution? 
If not, what does it usually mean?

Thank you

Comment: I've never heard that phrase before, but I would have to guess the authors mean observing the behavior of the algorithm (such as average time to convergence) over many sets of random data, rather a fixed data set.

Answer (score 0):

Now that I've talked to people working on algorithms in stochastic setting I can answer my own question:

Stochastic analysis of an algorithm means assuming the input data points to the algorithm are generated i.i.d from a fixed distribution, however the distribution is unknown.

In addition, one distinguishing feature of stochastic analysis is that its error bound should be proportional to $\frac{1}{n}$ for $n$ being the number of data points. This feature is often referred to as "statistical consistency" i.e. as we see more data points, our estimation/approximation becomes more accurate.